# Concertinaing cell array in nested for loop Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, for-loop, cell, nested-loops

I'm working in *Matlab*, in which nested for loop is used to collect data and store in cell array, However I want to collect data and the inner loop is collect further in the same cell array according to its position. However, I tried but it gives outter loop values indexes first, then the inner loop, I want to `cat` in the same cell array.
Is any *vectorization* trick possible or some other approach for solving my case?
`A` my cell array, I want to store both looping values in `A` by respective indexes which are important for me.
**My Code:**

```
for i=1:10
A{i}=i;
k=i;
for j=-270:90:270
if (j~=0)
A{i+k}=[j];
end
k=k+1;
end
end
```

**Actual Output:**
 Columns 1 through 14

```
 [1]    [2]    [3]    [4]    [5]    [6]    [7]    [8]    [9]    [10]    [-180]    [-270]    [-180]    [-270]

  Columns 15 through 26

    [-180]    [-270]    [-180]    [-270]    [-180]    [-270]    [-180]    [-90]    [180]    [90]    [180]    [270]
```

**Desired Output:**

```
 [1]  [-270 ] [-180 ]  [-90]    [ 90]   [180]   [270]  [2] [-270 ] [-180 ]  [-90]    [ 90]   [180]   [270]    [3] [-270 ] [-180 ]  [-90]    [ 90]   [180]   [270]    [4] [-270 ] [-180 ]  [-90]    [ 90]   [180]   [270]    [5]  [-270 ] [-180 ]  [-90]    [ 90]   [180]   [270]   [6]   [-270 ] [-180 ]  [-90]    [ 90]   [180]   [270]  [7]  [-270 ] [-180 ]  [-90]    [ 90]   [180]   [270]   [8]  [-270 ] [-180 ]  [-90]    [ 90]   [180]   [270]   [9]  [-270 ] [-180 ]  [-90]    [ 90]   [180]   [270]   [10]  [-270 ] [-180 ]  [-90]    [ 90]   [180]   [270]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
J = -270:90:270;
J = nonzeros(J); %// avoid zeros in J
N = numel(J);
for i = 1:10
    ii = (N+1)*(i-1)+1;
    A{ii} = i;
    for n = 1:N
        A{ii+n} = J(n);
    end
end
```

Comment: @AhsanAli Corrected answer

Comment: How about if I want to double/triple the inner loop? i.e again repetation of `A{ii+n} = J(n);`

Comment: @AhsanAli That would be a different question. Your original post doesn't say that